# Redux Media Field is not displaying default Image preview

Tags: wordpress, redux-framework

I am using Redux framework to add theme options in my Wordpress theme. Now my problem is, media field is not displaying the default image preview. My codes are as bellows-

```
Redux::setSection( $opt_name, array(
    'icon' => 'el el-smiley',
    'title' => 'Header Optipns',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'title' => __('Logo Uploader','zText'),
            'subtitle' => __('Upload your Logo', 'zText'),
            'desc' => __('Upload any image or logo whatever you like','zText'),
            'type' => 'media',
            'id' => 'logo-uplodaer',
            'default'  => array(
                'url'=> get_template_directory_uri().'/images/logo.png'
            ),
        ),
        array(
        'title' => 'Gender',
        'type' => 'radio',
        'id' => 'gender',
        'options' => array(
            '1' => 'Male',
            '2' => 'Female',
            '3' => 'Hurmoprodite'
        ),
        'default' => '2'

        ),
        array(
        'title' => 'Color',
        'type' => 'color',
        'id' => 'color',
        'drfault' => '#ffffff',
        'validate' => 'color'
        )
    )
)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

> You just click on Reset Section Button

[image]

This option is working for me!

Answer (score 0):

maybe the solution is simple?

Default: 'default_show' => 'true'
This is the variable that enabled or disables whether or not the field’s default value is displayed by the field’s title.
Found here -> https://docs.reduxframework.com/core/arguments/#default_show

OR

'save_defaults'        => true,
// On load save the defaults to DB before user clicks save or not

Found here -> sample-config.php line 120 -> set false to true.

all the best

Answer (score 0):

You can use the editor to add images through it.

Here's the code snippet.

Admin panel:

```
    $fields = array(
    'id'               => 'editor-text',
    'type'             => 'editor',
    'title'            => __('Editor Text', 'redux-framework-demo'), 
    'subtitle'         => __('Subtitle text would go here.', 'redux-framework-demo'),
    'default'          => 'Powered by Redux.',
    'args'   => array(
        'teeny'            => true,
        'textarea_rows'    => 10
    )
);
```

front end:

```
global $redux_demo;

echo 'Editor text: ' . $redux_demo['editor-text'];
```

Please give it a try.

Comment: Why use editor field to add media while media type exists? https://devs.redux.io/core-fields/media.html